# asset_path in scss file rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am having issues with asset_path in production. Rails 3.1.1

```
#config/environments/development.rb
Scc::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

and

```
#config/environments/production.rb
 Scc::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

I have the following code:

```
.right-bar-filler{
    background:url(asset_path('right_bar_filler.jpg', image)) repeat-y;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

In development it ends up being:

```
.right-bar-filler {
  background: url("/assets/right_bar_filler.jpg") repeat-y;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

In production it outputs as:

```
.right-bar-filler {
  background: url(asset_path("right_bar_filler.jpg", image)) repeat-y;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

What am I completely missing?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This doesn't look correct:

```
.right-bar-filler{
    background:url(asset_path('right_bar_filler.jpg', image)) repeat-y;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

If you want to use the `asset_path` helper, it needs to run inside the erb tags (<% %>)

```
.right-bar-filler{
    background:url(<%= asset_path('right_bar_filler.jpg', image) %>) repeat-y;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

and make sure you name the file correctly, i.e. `example_filename.css.erb`

---

**UPDATE**: Sorry, I didn't notice you were using SASS, not CSS. My above answer is not what you need.

Try this instead:

```
.right-bar-filler{
    background:url(asset-path('right_bar_filler.jpg', image)) repeat-y;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

I.e. I think the asset path helper uses hyphens in SASS, not underscores

http://rubydoc.info/github/petebrowne/sprockets-sass/master/Sprockets/Sass/Functions

Answer (score 0):

Did you rake assets:precompile? 
By default, Rails will not compile assets in production. The recommended workflow is to compile assets as part of your deployment.

Comment: Yes that is happening in my Capistrano deploy script.