# Finger Print Digest not appending with image path in Rails 3.2.22.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline, precompile

I have a css class declared in a CSS partial named '_city-images.css.scc' :

```
.city-art {
  background: url(image-path('cities-images.png')) no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is after compilation of assets via assets:precompile. The path generated by the 'image-path' helper is not generated with finger print.

The path generated is : https://abc.mysite.com/assets/cities-images.png
But it should be something like : https://abc.mysite.com/assets/cities-images-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png

Before you ask, the issue is only in .css.scss files. All the paths in other files are generating with fingerprints. 
Finger Printing is enabled as well in production.rb : config.assets.digest = true

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution which worked.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not used the `precompile` array yet, you can add your individual stylesheets and js (excluding partial scss files as partials get included in some other scss files, which you should include btw) inside `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
```

**Note**: always specify an expected compiled filename that ends with .js or .css, even if you want to add Sass or CoffeeScript files to the precompile array.

For your case, if your partial `_city-images.css.scss` is imported in some other scss `base.css.scss`, then just include `( base.css )` in the `precompile` array.

You may also wish to take a look at the official guide on [Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: Precompile array is already implemented and the partial is getting compiled with CSS as well.
The Problem is with the Image Path it is generating. 
It should generate image-path with Finger Print at the end like http://abc.mysite.com/assets/cities-images-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png

But its not appending XXXXXXXXX with the image path. 
Its something related with image-path('cities-images.png')  helper.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending hours, I have resolved the issue :

```
.city-art {
  background: url(asset-path('cities-images.png', image)) no-repeat;
}
```

Needed to use asset-path, with parameter image.

Also check this if someone gets a similar issue : [asset_path in scss file rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334573/asset-path-in-scss-file-rails)