# Where should I put the img of JavaScript plugin in rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to use a javascript plugin [jQuery lightSlider](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider). I don't want to use `yarn` or `npm` so I just copy the `css` and `js` file into `vendor` folder.

However, in css file, it includes an image as background img [link](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/blob/master/dist/css/lightslider.css#L160):

```
.lSAction > a {
    ...
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url('../img/controls.png');
    cursor: pointer;
    ...
}
```

I am not should where should I put the `controls.png`, I tried to put in `vendor/img` folder but it fails. I don't want to modify the css file as well since it's external file.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're pretty close to [**asset_path in scss file rails**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8334573/479863). Basically you'd edit the CSS file and use a helper.

Comment: @muistooshort The issue is I shouldn't change the source code of third party plugin

Comment: The problem with this is if you are precompiling it the path becomes something like `controls-hash1234567fghj.png`

Comment: and the css doesn't get it. so you can either add it into public folder but without precompiling the images

Comment: I don't really see an issue, you have to do this sort of thing all the time when the plugin references other files. You you can provide your own `.lSAction > a { background-image: ... }` bit of CSS in *your* CSS and let the cascade do its job if you want to leave it alone.

Comment: @muistooshort so that means this plugin cannot be used directly and I need to customise the css to make it work.

Comment: More or less, yes. You almost always have to customize things. If necessary (or preferred), you can put a `.lSAction > a` rule into your CSS to fix the `background-image` path and leave the plugin's stuff alone.